# How do I move a widget around on the screen?

Tags: menu, dojo, positioning

I have a `Menu` widget that I want to display whenever the user clicks on specific dom elements, but I *don't* want a `MenuBar`. What's the best way to do this? I've tried attaching click handlers to the relevant DOM elements and having the click handler display the `Menu`, but I can only get it to display the `Menu` in the area where the original declarative markup would have been rendered. I can't get it to move at all. I'm attempting to use `dojo.style(myWidget.domNode, 'top', calculatedTop)` (and the equivalent with `'left'`). What (obvious thing) am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the dijit's default [menu widget](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/Menu), I would think that you just need to specify the property `targetNodeIds` on the Menu Widget ([reference](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit/Menu/targetNodeIds)) to define where the context menu is relevant:

```
targetNodeIds (Defined by dijit.Menu)
    Array of dom node ids of nodes to attach to. Fill this with nodeIds upon widget creation and it becomes context menu for those nodes.
```

To get the popup showing on left click I believe you'd want to use the property `leftClickToOpen`:

```
// leftClickToOpen: [const] Boolean
//      If true, menu will open on left click instead of right click, similiar to a file menu.
//defaults to false
leftClickToOpen: false,
```

Specifying this declaratively would look like:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.Menu" data-dojo-props="targetNodeIds: ['nodeId1','nodeId2','nodeId3'], leftClickToOpen:true"
        style="display: none;">
<!-- Your content here -->
</div>
```

Comment: That sounds promising, but I have a few questions: How do I specify this using the declarative style? and How do I trigger it so it happens when the user clicks an area instead of right-clicks? Sorry if this is obvious stuff, but I'm a total n00b at Dojo.

Comment: Should I be doing anything special to get the `data-dojo-type` style to work? If I use that instead of `dojoType`, my rendering goes completely haywire (stair-step from top-left to bottom-right). Also, is there a way to get the menu to open on hover, a la CSS-based rollover menus? Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe there is any built in support for roll-over, although it probably wouldn't be too difficult to implement into a widget that inherits the dijit.Menu properties.  Could you post a small example of the  issue you are having on something like jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I'll try editing the file down into a small reproducible test case and get back to you. Until then, it's essentially a form with some different input types, a nav menu, and a (custom, corporate) theme. If I use `dojoType`, things work fine, but if I use `data-dojo-type` then I get the stairstep effect. Thanks for all the help, btw.

Comment: Narrowing it down is generally a good way to isolate what the problem is as well.  I was making the assumption you are using dojo 1.6+, which is where the data-dojo-* attributes were introduced.  If you are  using a previous version of dojo those attributes will not work correctly

Comment: OK, so work on the narrowing-down process seems to indicate the problem is with the custom, corporate theme. When I switched to `claro` from the Google CDN, I no longer see the problem caused by switching to the `data-dojo` style. I'm guessing the corporate theme is based on an older version. Thanks again for all the help! One (hopefully) final thing: do you have any good recommendations for guides to creating your own Dojo widgets? My copies of "Dojo: The Definitive Guide" and "Getting Started with Dojo" just landed on my desk this morning, if that helps.

Comment: [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/wa-aj-dojotool/index.html), [DojoToolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/recipes/custom_widget/), and [EnterpriseDojo] (http://www.enterprisedojo.com/2010/09/21/introduction-to-custom-dojo-widgets/) all have good starts to creating dojo widgets.